# PHP/HTML Add onclick function to subcategories with certain name

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement

I am trying to add an onclick function for only certain recursively generated subcategories.

This code currently displays the subcategories correctly:

```
                    <?php if($parent) { ?>
                      <?php $search_params['sCategory'] = $parent['pk_i_id']; ?>
                      <a href="<?php echo osc_search_url($search_params); ?>" class="parent active" data-name="sCategory" data-val="<?php echo $parent['pk_i_id']; ?>">
                        <span class="name"><?php echo $parent['s_name']; ?></span><em>(<?php echo ($parent['i_num_items'] == '' ? 0 : $parent['i_num_items']); ?>)</em>
                      </a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php foreach($categories as $c) { ?>
                      <?php $search_params['sCategory'] = $c['pk_i_id']; ?>

                      <a href="<?php echo osc_search_url($search_params); ?>" class="child<?php if($c['pk_i_id'] == $search_cat_id) { ?> active<?php } ?>" data-name="sCategory" data-val="<?php echo $c['pk_i_id']; $
                        <span class="name"><?php echo $c['s_name'];?></span><em>(<?php echo ($c['i_num_items'] == '' ? 0 : $c['i_num_items']); ?>)</em>
                      </a>

                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>
```

I would like to call say functionX(); written in JS for only the subcategory named "catx".

FunctionX() is working correctly when called else where.

I've tried something like this but get a White screen:

```
    <?php if($search_params == "catX") {
    echo '<a onclick="functionX();" href="<?php echo osc_search_url($search_params); ?>" class="parent active" data-name="sCategory" data-val="<?php echo $parent['pk_i_id']; ?>">
      <span class="name"><?php echo $parent['s_name']; ?></span><em>(<?php echo ($parent['i_num_items'] == '' ? 0 : $parent['i_num_items']); ?>)</em>
    </a>;'
    } else {
    echo '<a href="<?php echo osc_search_url($search_params); ?>" class="parent active" data-name="sCategory" data-val="<?php echo $parent['pk_i_id']; ?>">
      <span class="name"><?php echo $parent['s_name']; ?></span><em>(<?php echo ($parent['i_num_items'] == '' ? 0 : $parent['i_num_items']); ?>)</em>
      </a>;' ?>
```

Pretty new to this, thanks for the help!

Comment: Something's not right with the code you provided. The line with your second link tag ends with a `$` and in the next line, despite you started PHP code via `<?php`, you continue with HTML.

Comment: Just look into the php error logs, a lot of your second code block is not right. Php code is not closed and opend properly, and you are useing php opening and closing tags with an echo. This causes a white page.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `echo` you are using `'` to specify the borders of what you are going to output.

In your code you have echo 'Some content' but your content contains an `'` aswell. Named: `$parent['pk_i_id']`

There a several ways to do this. Here is an example ([Concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)):

```
echo '<a onclick="functionX();" href="' . osc_search_url($search_params) . '">Click me</a>'; // ...
```

The inline notation is useful, in case you have surrounding HTML-Code:

```
<b>My name is<?php echo $name ?></b>
```

Just dont mix em :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an approach that works for everyone but in this kind of scenario I find it visually helpful (and very useful if I need to debug anything) to **incrementally build** a string using

- statements
- variables; and
- conditional statements

and *then* `echo` the string, once I have built it.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$Item_Number = ($parent['i_num_items'] === '') ? 0 : $parent['i_num_items'];

$Link = '';
$Link .= '<a ';

if ($search_params === 'catX') {

  $Link .= 'onclick="functionX();" ';
}

$Link .= 'href="'.osc_search_url($search_params).'" class="parent active" data-name="sCategory" data-val="'.$parent['pk_i_id'].'">';
$Link .= '<span class="name">'.$parent['s_name'].'</span>';
$Link .= '<em>('.$Item_Number.')</em>';
$Link .= '</a>';

echo $Link;

?>
```